# Symfony ResponseEvent arguments

Tags: php, symfony

I'm following a Symfony tutorial and am currently on [The Event Dispatcher](https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/event_dispatcher.html) section. In the first code block (after the composer part) I'm instructed to set up the dispatcher

```php
// dispatch a response event
$this->dispatcher->dispatch(new ResponseEvent($response, $request), 'response');
```

I'm using PHPStorm, and when I create the `ResponseEvent` class it is asking for 4 arguments

```php
new ResponseEvent($kernel, $request, $requestType, $response)
```

While I could create a `$kernel` element by importing the `HttpKernelInterface`, I'm unsure if this is correct.

I also have no idea where to get the `$requestType` from, since the `ResponseEvent` class definition says that this should be of type `int` and I only know of request types in string format (e.g. 'GET', 'POST' etc).

[Here is the full file](https://pastebin.com/ysy4vQKP) in case I have made a mistake elsewhere.

Comment: Your IDE is actually picking up the HttpKernel ResponseEvent.  In the tutorial your are following it is up to you to make your own ResponseEvent.  More than likely you just need to remove a use statement.

Comment: PhpStorm can be annoying when it (seemingly always) suggests the wrong class name, if there's another of the same name, first in the list of their typeahead feature. Even after selecting some other class multiple times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial that you are following wants you to use the `Simplex` `ResponseEvent`, that method signature is for the kernel `ResponseEvent`

At the top of your file you should see something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ResponseEvent;
```

Replace it with

```
use Simplex\ResponseEvent;
```